# Calculating distance between coordinates from point to a box?

Tags: java, distance, wgs84

I have two different WGS84 coordinates, A and B. A is just a (lat,lon,z) point and B is a (lat,lon,z) point inside the center of a box with the dimension height, width, depth (in meters).

I need to calculate the distance from A to the box, not to the center of the box but to the closest side/surface of the box. Any ideas?

I already have a method to calculate between two coordinates ((lat,lon) to (lat,lon)).

Comment: Mind that if your "Box" is not a circle/sphere, then orientation matters. Distance from center to the center of a side is smaller than to a corner.

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question but yes the box (rectangular block) is not a circle/sphere :)

Comment: What I mean is: Imagine Your Point to be any Point on a Circle line around the center of the box. Let's assume the box is oriented with a corner pointing to North. Then the length of a line from point on circle and side of the box at 0° would be different from a line at 45° ... In 3D it's even one dimension more complicated :)